# Will not having Google billing details break the map?

Tags: google-maps

After reading this article: https://mapsplatform.googleblog.com/2018/05/introducing-google-maps-platform.html

We need to know what will happen to the embedded maps on our clients's websites in case they don't add the billing information in the API key account. Will the maps break on their site until they update these billing details?

Also, if they are billing details in their API key account, are they able to pay other Google Products with this information.

Is this action urgent?

Comment: Questions here are seen by a wide variety of users, and are best not addressed to Google Maps Tech Support. I've edited it with that in mind.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50482154/is-it-compulsory-to-enable-billing-account-by-june-11-2018-through-credit-card

Answer (score 0):

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50568604/9496752)

Billing details are compulsory if you are exceeding free quota worth of $200