# Enabling billing for new Google Maps Platform

Tags: google-api, google-places-api, google-places

I was under the impression that requests made to the Google Places API would no longer work starting today (6/11) without enabling billing.  I have yet to enable billing, and I am still getting results back as usual.  Has this date been pushed back?

Comment: Yes, the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/) says that new prices are coming on July 16, 2018. Also have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50568604/5140781

Comment: The delay was also announced in Google Maps Platform blog: https://mapsplatform.googleblog.com/2018/06/new-plan-changes-going-into-effect-july.html