# Google maps pins on map pricing in August 2018

Tags: android, google-maps

Do we really have to have a credit card on file to put a map with pins on it in an Android app?

It seemed like we worked it out to a 'no' but it's still unclear, and transition tool says 'This project does not have a billing account. You will need to add billing information for this project to continue to use Google Maps Platform.' for an app that literally is nothing but a map with 50 pins for the 50 capitals.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spiritflightapps.capitalsflashcards

Yes, I realize this is very similar to 
[Is it mandatory to add billing information to Google Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51209045/is-it-mandatory-to-add-billing-information-to-google-maps)

but I'm looking for an *official* answer - will existing apps with only markers on map stop working in 4 days - yes or no?

Comment: Google will create special billing account for you if you don't enable yourself by July 16, 2018. This billing account will work as long as you didn't exceed $200 credit. Once exceeded, the billing account will be blocked. To unblock it you will need add credit card information. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50482154/is-it-compulsory-to-enable-billing-account-by-june-11-2018-through-credit-card/50568604#50568604